# How to move windows desktops (workspaces)?

Tags: windows-10, workspace

How do you move/swap/change order of Windows 10 desktops? Is there an ability to drag and drop them?

Answer (score 1):

**This is not possible on Windows 10 (2004) currently**.

But there is a workaround. We have still the ability to drag on drop windows of one workspace to another.

Suppose you have opened 3 workspaces and order in the pattern 2,1,3. First click the Workspace button at taskbar. Then click second workspace and in below in the row of windows, drag and drop them to first workspace. So, switch to desktop 1 and drag its windows to workspace 2 and at last workspace 3 stays in its place.

Comment: Seems that the order should be: New workspace 4, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 1, 4 -> 2, remove 4.

Comment: @harrymc getting confused. Why need the fourth workspace? As we are transferring 2 to 1 then 1 to 2 and keeping 3 as is.

Comment: Presumably there is already something in all workspaces. To avoid mixing windows from two different workspaces in one, requires a fourth empty workspace.